# What is this short blade with a hole at one end?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

[image: find element]

What is this element ID?? Can you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a [98347](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98347&idColor=1), a.k.a Wing 1 x 4 with Pin Hole

[image]